# Railstutorial.org 6.2.4 Format Validation

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, format, railstutorial.org

Working my way through Hartl's Railstutorial.org, an I run into an issue getting the test to work on the Format validation with the email.

My user.rb is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base       
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum:50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

user_spec.rb is:
    require 'spec_helper'

```
describe User do
  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email)}

  it { should be_valid}

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email=" "}
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name="a"*51}
    it {should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org 
                     example.user@foo. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        expect(@user).not_to be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My error listing is as follows:
    Failures:

```
  1) User
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid}
       expected #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Email is invalid

     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:13:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User when email format is valid should be valid
     Failure/Error: expect(@user).to be_valid
       expected #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@foo.COM". cre
ated_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors. Email is invalid
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:45:in 'block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:43:in 'each'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:43:in 'block (3 levels) in >top (required)>'

Finished in 0.03 seconds
8 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:13 # User
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:41 # User when email format is valid should be
valid
```

I am sure that I am missing something minor (when I have this much trouble figuring it out, it usually is minor). Would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

The exact code in the tutorial is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

your `VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z]+\z/i` lacks some letters.

Comment: Thanks tk. I had been looking mostly in the user_spec for an answer. Much appreciated!